# Including and excluding types from template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I want to inhibit certain types from template instantiation. I want to implement an algorithm in a library which works only for real numbers, and not for complex  or integer types. So user instantiations with float/double/long double/mpf_class should be ok, but i.e. `complex<float>` *must* not occur.

Specializations would produce code bloat with code that will never be used. (I could generate ctors only throwing exceptions).

```cpp
template<typename T>
void work (T & result, T const & input) { /* work for any real type */ }
```

Ideally there should be a compiler message saying "this ... instantiation is not allowed".

Explicit lists of allowed templates would be too restrictive.

Comment: Do you know of `static_assert`? `enable_if`?

Comment: a `static_assert` with `std::is_floating_point` would work

Answer (score 3):

You can use `static_assert` to generate the exact compile-time error message you want:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void work (T & result, T const & input)
{
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<T>::value, "Only floating point types are allowed.");

    // ...
}
```

If you're using C++17, you can write it a bit shorter:

```
static_assert(std::is_floating_point_v<T>, "Only floating point types are allowed.");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just define that particular specialization of the template as `delete`d, if you want to prevent instantiation for a particular type.

A minimal example preventing instantiation with `T=int`:

```
template<typename T>
void work (T & result, T const & input) { (void)result; (void)input; }


template<>
void work (int & result, int const & input) = delete;

int main()
{
    float f1 = 3.14;
    float f2 = 1.414;
    work(f1, f2); //works

    int i1 = 1;
    int i2 = 2;
    work(i1, i2); //Doesn't work

}
```

The compiler will complain for the instantiation with `int`.

```
error: use of deleted function 'void work(T&, const T&) [with T = int]'
   16 |     work(i1, i2); //Doesn't work
```

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/FWVHxh)

Comment: @brf: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, there's also SFINAE.

```
template<typename T>
auto work (T & result, T const & input) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>
{
  // ..
}
```

The `void` is omitted because it's the default type `enable_if_t` resolves to when the condition holds. It's just a stylistic choice.

The difference here is that the function won't even be considered to exist in overload resolution. So you can check if `work` is callable with an argument in other SFINAE contexts. Putting the check in a the function template's signature is the only way to accomplish that.